# Selecting based on __key__ (a unique identifier) in google appengine [Java]

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gql

I have

```
public class QuantityType {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;

    @Persistent
    private String type;
}
```

I am trying to setup a query to get the right QuantityType by it's key

```
gql = "select * from QuantityType where __key__='aght52oobW1hIHTWVzc2FnZRiyAQw'";
```

But its not working because

BadFilterError: BadFilterError: invalid filter: **key** filter value must be a Key; received aght52oobW1hIHTWVzc2FnZRiyAQw (a str).

I have also tried to use

```
gql = "select * from QuantityType where __key__=='" + KeyFactory.stringToKey(qTypeKey)+"'";
```

but it's not working..

How can I get a specific object from my datastore by it's key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should never construct a GQL string by hand - this leads to injection vulnerabilities. Instead, declare and pass in parameters, as documented [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queriesandindexes.html#Introducing_Queries).

To retrieve an entity by key, though, you don't need to do a query at all: Use getObjectById, as documented [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/creatinggettinganddeletingdata.html#Getting_an_Object_By_Key). This is significantly faster than using a query.

Comment: and the solution is 
QuantityType q = pm.getObjectById(QuantityType.class, KeyFactory.stringToKey(qTypeKey));
Thanks